# S3 Bulk Data Update

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a bunch of json documents which have the same of set of fields stored in a S3 bucket. In order to update the status field from "pending" to "complete" for all these records , should I get the documents one by one , update the status field and put them back to S3 one by one or is there a way of doing bulk updates to these documents in S3 using the S3 keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a large number of objects, I would consider doing this with [Amazon S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops.html). You could write a simple Lambda function using boto3 to get an object from S3, update the contents, and put the object back into S3. S3 Batch would orchestrate calling the Lambda for each object.

For a small number of objects, this might be overkill and you could simply use boto3 to enumerate the objects, get them one by one, modify each, and put it back.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. The number of requests in my case is less than 10. So I'll probably get them one by one and modify! However its useful in case I encounter a batch use case in future.

Comment: BTW, another possible design here would use object tags. The JSON file would originally be uploaded with its usual contents but *without* the status attribute. The status would be a tag of status=pending. Once your process has decided that a give JSON file is complete, it would re-tag the object with status=complete (or simply remove the status=pending tag to indicate complete, whatever works better for you).

Comment: That's a nice suggestion too. I'll explore that as swell. Thanks again.